# mysql sum lowest prices

Tags: mysql, sum, min

I have an apartment calendar table for displaying prices to users for each day.
On this table, some of the apartments include rooms (id_room) to rent:

table columns / records example:

```
id_apart | id_room | date       | price | promo_price
1        |    1    | 03-03-2013 | 20.00 | 0
1        |    1    | 04-03-2013 | 20.00 | 0
1        |    2    | 03-03-2013 | 50.00 | 45.00
1        |    2    | 04-03-2013 | 50.00 | 45.00
```

I want to get as a result, a string that has 'price' and 'promo_price' concatenated with total SUM of the lowest prices found for the apartment / rooms between two dates.

This query is summing all room prices for the apartment and i can't figure out how to use MIN on this one, to sum ONLY the prices of the CHEAPEST room:

```
select 
    concat(sum(if(promo_price>0,promo_price,price)), 
    "---",
    sum(price)) 
from 
    apart 
where 
    id_apart=215 
    and date>= "2013-03-03" 
    and date<"2013-03-05"
```

The result from this query is:
90---140

Legend: first string number is sum of 'promo_price'; second number sum of 'price'

Comment: what result you want get ?

Comment: My answer was edited with the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(promo_price, "--", price) from apart 
where id_apart=215 and date >= "2013-03-03" and date < "2013-03-05" 
and (promo_price + price)) = (select min(promo_price + price) from apart);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
select concat(if(promo_price>0, 'true', sum(promo_price)),'---', sum(price)) 
from aprt where id_apart = 215 and date between "2013-03-03" and "2013-03-05"
```

Answer (score 0):

i think is this what you looking for

```
   select if(promo_price = 0,concat(sum(price),"---", sum(price)) ,sum(price)) as pri
  from apart  
   where id_apart=1 and `date`>= "03-03-2013" and `date` < "05-03-2013"
   and promo_price = 0
```

OUTPUT.

```
   PRIS
```

> **40---40**

**obs** note that i made id_apart=1  from your above example .

Comment: This is the result that i'm getting. I want it to return only the SUM of the CHEAPEST room. I should get: 40---40

Answer (score 0):

Is this answer u looking for?

```
select 
concat(sum(if(promo_price>0,promo_price,price)), 
"---",
sum(price)) from apart group by id_room 
having sum(price) + sum(promo_price) = 
(select min(sum(price) + sum(promo_price)) from apart where id_apart =1 
group by id_room);
```

Output :40 --- 40